# Два maven проекта в одном

Tags: java, maven, docker

У меня есть два отдельных maven проекта data_importer и data_exporter. Оба проекта собираются в свои отдельные Docker контейнеры.

В этих проектах есть часть одинакового кода, например POJO классы, ConsumerKafka, ProducerKafka, HttpServer. В связи с чем необходимо объединить проекты но так, чтобы при сборке Docker контейнера можно было указать запуск importer или exporter.

Как это можно реализовать? Какой здесь архитектурных подход использовать лучше?

Comment: сделайте один проект, и класс с `main`, у которого две статический метода: запуск проекта1 и проекта2. В main b решайте, что запускать

Comment: Попробуйте решить это с помощью профилирования. Похоже что это ваш случай.